# What to say when quitting after 2 days

Tags: resignation

I recently joined a company.I am BE pass out and I want to pursue higher education in my domain.I attended office for 2 days and now I am realising this is not something I want to do and it's better I completely divert myself towards my MS plans and get my application process done in time.My company has this policy where you have to give notice period 3 months before, otherwise you are obliged to pay them, which I don't want to do.The good side is my training hasn't started yet.Is there any chance that if I quit on my third day they won't make any compulsion to pay them and approve my resignation.My main concern is I do not want to make payment to them since I have attended only for 2 days and didn't attend any sessions as such.What reason should I give them for quitting?should I be honest or say some family problem, please guide me.This is my first job and I don't know what step should I be taking next.

Comment: Do you have trial time? In some places there is usually one or two weeks to see if for the candidate and the company if it was a good decision (for you to work there, for them to hire you ). During this time is often easier to quit. Read carefully your contract to find if you have such period.

Comment: Vote to close as this question is company specific issue. Normally, you can quit provided you give proper notice (in many countries, you are required to give two weeks notice). Now, the OP specifies that his company requires 3 months notice. Please specify the location so that we can proceed to answer.

Comment: Also, please explain what "_BE pass out_" means.

Comment: Three month notice? What country is this?

Comment: 3 months motice: I'd guess India. Their system is unlike that in most countries, to the point where I don't even try to answer those.

Comment: The other four close votes were for "off-topic", but I marked it as a duplicate of a question that has the same underlying problem.  Snehal, we can't interpret your company's or location's laws and rules, nor tell you what to do, but I hope the linked question is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance that if I quit on my third day they won't make any
>   compulsion to pay them and approve my resignation?

**No**, they would make it a compulsion to stay for at least for the notice period, or pay the required amount. If it is a rule, then it should be followed.

> i do not want to make payment to them since i have attended only for 2
>   days and didn't attended any sessions as such

What if you did not attend any sessions? The company have filled the position with you. Now, as you are quitting, they have to put efforts again, for filling that position, ditch and prepare the paperwork which they were preparing for you, and design the training modules for the new candidate. So, there is a lot of efforts involved. And that's exactly the reason why companies have notice periods.

So, I really don't see a way you can make them accept your resignation(and most importantly, as your reason is not even close to convincing.)

You might want to talk to the HR about it, but you have a very bleak chance of getting out immediately, without paying the caution amount.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have included it in the last paragraph.  But yeah, the OP have a very bleak chance.